# I want to use something like V.O. or O.S to indicate my character is in a shadow, what should I do?

Tags: formatting, screenwriting

I want to use something like V.O. or O.S to indicate my character is in a shadow, what should I do?

I like what the Wachowskis did in the [Matrix](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/the_matrix.pdf), which is a major influence for me.

Would readers throw it in the trash bin automatically if I did the following? (I know the below formatting is awful, but I'm only concerned about the bold portions).

> Bruce (Left Shadow)
>
> ...dialog here ...
>
> Vince (Right Shadow)
>
> ...dialog here ...

(and later in the script after they come out of the shadows)

> Bruce
>
> ...dialog here ...
>
> Vince
>
> ...dialog here ...

Thanks!
John

Comment: Are you writing a script? I think script writing has pretty firm conventions to follow for off-screen voices.

Comment: @KenMohnkern Yes, and roger that... I guess I'll search for an example and use that as an influence

Answer (score 2):

If it's a script then it's probably alright, although for a book you can just state the fact in begging like
"2 shadows were seen talking on the wall. The left shadow made a hand gestures [any gesture] and Bruce's voice came in saying [insert dialogue] . The other stayed still as the silence prevailed. Suddenly the right shadow caught the collar of other and Vince said- you don't talk to me like that" and then once its established that who is whom. You can carry forward as any normal conversation.